# How can I use more than 1 column in ORDER BY in FQL?

Tags: facebook-fql

I've got a question about FQL: Is it possible to do an ORDER BY on more than one column?

The following FQL query works:

```
SELECT uid,first_name,last_name 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 123) 
ORDER BY last_name
```

However, this one doesn't:

```
SELECT uid,first_name,last_name
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 123) 
ORDER BY last_name, first_name
```

It returns:

```
"error": {
"message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected ',' at position 122.", 
"type": "OAuthException", 
"code": 601
```

Is this working as intended, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The ORDER BY function isn't well documented. It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. I get the same OAuth errors when I try using two columns. Note that some of the married women I am friends with who have their maiden names in quotes appear before the A's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. I recently filed a documentation bug that explains FQL `ORDER BY`can only contain one column. So it is indeed working as intended.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/148360015351840